# Google AppEngine flex overwriting public folder permissions on deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php, google-app-engine-deploy

I'm deploying a PHP app on the AppEngine Flexible environment. I have a command in my post-deploy-cmd scripts in my composer.json file to set permissions for the public/app folder (`chmod -R 755 public\/app`). However, when I deploy my app, the entire public folder's permissions get overwritten with 550.

I can see in the logs that the following command runs right after my deployment commands - `+ chmod -R 550 /app/public`

How can I run my command after that or stop that command from running at all? Any workarounds?